# adding and using new parameter to function

Tags: java

I hava a function like this:

```
doSomething(){
  Object a = getA() //can return null
  // a lot of additional code
}
```

... but i want to add a possibility to give object a into method so i created a new method:

```
doSomething(){
  doSomething(null);
}

doSomething(Object a){
  if(a == null){
    a = getA()
  }  
}
```

but this is not correct because the object passed into method can also be null and then i wanto to it to null, not use getA() method so i did something like this:

```
doSomething(){
  doSomething(null, false);
}

doSomething(Object a, boolean useObject){
  if(!useObject){
    a = getA()
  }
```

but this seems kind of ugly. Is there a better solution?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

How about :

```
doSomething()
{
    Object a = getA();
    doSomething(a);
}

doSomething(Object a)
{

}
```

This way, if someone calls `doSomething(null)` you don't call `getA()`.

Answer (score 0):

You can test if a is not null

```
doSomething(){
  doSomething(null);
}

doSomething(Object a){
  if(a != null){
    a = getA()
  }
}
```